# Jquery Animation error " ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am getting the following error:

ReferenceError: `$ is not defined`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        #navBox {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: #004C7E;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navBox"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).click(function () {
            $("#navBox").effect("shake");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I using an outdated jquery version? I was trying to follow this guide: http://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/

Comment: Are you viewing this as a local file? Does the url start with `file://`?

Comment: Are you running this off of the c: drive so the url looks like `file://...`? If yes, don;t do that, Set up a local server with Apache or IIS. It is simple.

Comment: checking your network tab, should be easy to target your issue

Comment: thanks!! yes it was a local file and I wasn't putting the protocol information in the urls. That was stupid of me haha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I expect if you look in your web console, you'll see some 404 errors.

This:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

...uses a [*protocol-relative URL*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html). That means if the page was loaded from `http://example.com`, the protocol will be `http:`; if from `https://example.com`, it'll be `https:`. And critically, if it's `file://c/your/stuff`, then it's `file:` and the source doesn't exist.

Using a protocol-relative URL is fine, but if you do, you can't open HTML files directly from your local filesystem and expect them to work. You have to open them through a web server (you can readily install a simple web server on your local system).